# Regex for only Select queries?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for a regex which only allows select queries strictly,
No inserts, deletes, alters or anything of that sort can be allowed and the query can have multiple lines..

I tried

```
var pattern="(^select)^((?!insert|delete|alter).)*$";

var pattern=^(?!insert|delete|alter|modify|add|create|drop|truncate|rename|update|rollback|commit|grant|revoke|savepoint)(.(?!insert|delete|alter|modify|add|create|drop|truncate|rename|update|rollback|commit|grant|revoke|savepoint))*$";
```

How to make it not match insert or any keywords on multiple lines (in javascript).

It fails in

```
Eg: select *
insert 
into
```

which means it should start with "select" and cannot have insert anywhere in the query but this doesn`t work.

Comment: Why are you doing regex validation of SQL queries? Its possible, but this sounds sketchy. Why not restrict user permissions so they can only perform `select`s and nothing else?

Comment: Agreed, this is just an extra safety measure .. And I also want to make sure the string doesn`t have any insert, delete keywords even after the first Select .. So strin.startswith() is not good enough.

Comment: What if the user wants to perform the query `SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Body LIKE "%delete%"`?

Comment: Why do you care if there are keywords after the first `SELECT`? Putting `DELETE` after `SELECT` won't delete anything. You can't write a query like `SELECT foo AND DELETE IT`.

Comment: But what if its a multiline script .. Only select at the start won`t work. Coz if the second line has an insert .. it would be a problem .. and not each line will have selects .. it might have a SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this idea, as mentioned in the comments.  But as far as how to actually accomplish this:

```
/^select(?:(?!insert|delete|alter)[\s\S])*$/i
```

This will make sure `select` (case-insensitively) is the first word.  Then I used the rest of your expression almost exactly.  I threw the `*` repetition into a non-capture group, and updated the `.` to `[\s\S]` (because `.` matches any character ***except*** newline).

Comment: What about this: `select * from actions where name="undelete";`?

Comment: *There are a lot of problems with this idea, as mentioned in the comments.* -- I figured OP could still see an expression to learn how to do what they wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't easily (if at all) possible.**

There are innumerate innocuous queries that a user may want to run that any sane regex will pick up. For example, if a StackOverflow user want to find all questions that include the text "delete", the query may end up being:

```
SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Body LIKE "%delete%"
```

Regex word boundaries (`\b`) won't work as there is a word boundary between `%` and `delete`. Adding spaces might work, ie. `/^ *delete/` but what if a user wants to find just the word delete and does:

```
SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Body LIKE "% delete %"
```

Still a valid query. As such, unless you force the user to never be able query for any word that is also an SQL command in your database, then you are out of luck.

Comment: But what if its a multiline script .. Only select at the start won`t work. Coz if the second line has an insert .. it would be a problem .. and not each line will have selects .. it might have a SET .